# Python MySQL Connector Execute Stalling

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am using the mysql connector library to execute queries on a database, but the program stalls on the execute line. I have used the mysql connector with my database before and did not have this problem. I am running the following code:

```
    import mysql.connector
    
    # connect to database
    print("Connecting to database ...")
    webc_db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = host,
        user = user,
        password = password,
        database = database
    )
    print("Done.\n")
    # create database cursor
    db_cursor = webc_db.cursor()
    
    print("executing query....")
    db_cursor.execute("select * from terms;")
    result  = db_cursor.fetchall()
    for line in result:
        `enter code here`print(line)
    print("Done.\n")
```

and my output looks like this, stalling on the execution of the query

```
python test.py
Connecting to database ...
Done.

executing sql....
```

Any idea what could be causing the problem? I do not think the problem has to do with the size of the query because it is stalling with a drop table command as well as a create table command. I can execute these directly through mysql just fine and have been able to use the mysql connector before in another script.

Comment: try to Limit the output to 10 and see if that show 10 results

Comment: @nbk I added limit 10 to the end of the select statement and it is still not completing. It also stalls with the drop table command so I do not think it has to do with the size of query.

Comment: have you workbench or so, and can directyl enter commands, show processlist and see if there is something blocking. also you shoud chekc for Locks

Comment: @nbk this fixed my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As offered by @nbk in the comments, I checked the process list in mysql-workbench using:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

And found all of the queries that I have been trying to make in my python code that have been stalled. In the process list the queries were listed as "waiting for table metadata lock." I figured this may have been present because of an earlier query that showed in the process list, so I killed the process using the KILL command:

```
KILL [process id];
```

and the stalled queries were no longer in the process list. I checked the problem in python and the executing stall no longer occurs.